# Paginator only working for one web page django

Tags: python, html, django

Paginator is only working for the first index page but it doesn't work on the profile page

```
def profile(request, profile):
    cur_profile = User.objects.get(username=profile)
    user_posts = Posts.objects.filter(creator=cur_profile.id).all().order_by('-id')
    follow_num = cur_profile.following.all().order_by('id')
    following_num = cur_profile.followers.all().order_by('id')
    paginator2 = Paginator(user_posts, 5)
    page_numberr = request.GET.get(paginator2)
    page_objj = paginator2.get_page(page_numberr)
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", {
        "profile": profile,
        "cur_profile": cur_profile,
        "user_posts": user_posts,
        "follow_num": follow_num.count(),
        "following_num": following_num.count(),
        "page_objj": page_objj
    })
```

my html is this

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_objj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_objj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_objj.number }} of {{ page_objj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_objj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_objj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_objj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

My first page had the same variable names so i changed them but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I made all html pages extend from an initial one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def profile(request, profile):
    cur_profile = User.objects.get(username=profile)
    user_posts = Posts.objects.filter(creator=cur_profile.id).all().order_by('-id')
    follow_num = cur_profile.following.all().order_by('id')
    following_num = cur_profile.followers.all().order_by('id')
    paginator2 = Paginator(user_posts, 5)
    page_numberr = request.GET.get('page')
    page_objj = paginator2.get_page(page_numberr)
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", {
        "profile": profile,
        "cur_profile": cur_profile,
        "user_posts": user_posts,
        "follow_num": follow_num.count(),
        "following_num": following_num.count(),
        "page_objj": page_objj
    })
```

Comment: I tried that before it did not work

Comment: @Arjun Shekhawat please describe the changes you made in one short sentence.